# Ajax post gives 404 error in Spring

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I am making an ajax call to the controller from jsp overlay page. The controller is invoked, but the browser throws a 404 error page. I want the control to be on the overlay page

**jsp page snippet:**

```
            <s:form action="expressEOI" class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="expressEOIBean">
                        <div class="form-group"></div>

             ........

            <button class="btn btn-info" name="eoiSavebtn" id="eoiSavebtn">Please
                                        Save </button>


        $(document).ready(function() {
        .....
        $('#eoiSavebtn').attr('onClick','javascript:saveEOI("'+contextPath+'","'+ applicationId+'")');
```

**ajax call:**

```
            $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url :  window.location.protocol + "//"+ window.location.host + contextPath+ "/saveEOI",
                    cache : false,
                    data: {'applicationId' : applicationId},

                    success : function(e) { alert("success");   },

                    error : function(e) { }
                });
```

***controller:***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveEOI", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEOI(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("ExpressEOIController :: Save EOI() : Start");
        }
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug the application step by step

From `postman`, curl or any other rest client try to hit a post call with the payload body as empty JSON.If this also return 404, then it is a server problem.If it succeeds or throw any java error then we know it is UI issue. Also make sure to add content type header as `'application/json'`

This will help in isolating the issue